# How to describe a platform to non-developers?

Tags: system

I've been trying to describe the concept of platforms to some non-developer people on my team. I'm trying to explain how platforms are more than just tools and environments. For example, the Facebook Platform. How to describe the fact that the platform is more than just the website, but includes protocols like XFBML, opengraph, etc.

Facebook Platform is one example, but I would be interested if anyone has an abstracted way to describe what 'platforms' are in the tech world. I've had difficulty explaining this concept before in situations unrelated to flash.

Analogies that aren't tech related would be helpful as well.

Comment: I personally don’t think the Flash platform is a good example for what developers usually think of. The Facebook platform is probably a better example, but I can’t really think of a good explanation right now, so I’ll leave that to others.

Comment: I agree, that's a better example of what I'm getting at. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a "restaurant" metaphor, myself: Think of the kitchen, the bar, the dining room as components to the platform. How the decor can change in the dining room without changing the function, but can affect how customers perceive the business. How the recipes instruct the cooks, and the interactions with the wait staff can all affect different aspects of the business much like different pieces of your platform can be modified to affect different aspects of your business. Oh, and don't forget management!

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start.

Answer (score 1):

I would say something about it being all-inclusive and extending to include all functionality that the entire ecosystem around that particular piece of software needs to thrive.

The Wikipedia page might help in putting it into words: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_platform